# grunt + bower task gives fatal error: Unexpected token {

Tags: gruntjs, bower

I know these are too old environments but still using..

When I run `grunt`, the fatal error happens.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:387:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/application/staging.retrip.jp/node_modules/bower-registry-client/node_modules/request/lib/cookies.js:3:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

I'm not familiar with grunt + bower task..
Please help..